# Mail is not received

Tags: server, email, postfix, dovecot, roundcube

I have a configured a mail server in my system,
After configuring I am facing a problem that I can send a mail but I can't view the mail sent from external or local.

```
Test case :
```

1. Sending mail to external eg(testing@gmail.com) **Success** (shows in
   sent mail received in mail inbox)
2. Sending mail to local eg(testing@softsolutions4u.info) **Failed** (shows in sent mail but sent mail is not showing in
   testing@softsolutions4u.info inbox)
3. Sending mail From external eg(testing@gmail.com to testing@softsolutions4u.info) **Failed** (shows in sent
   mail(testing@gmail.com) success but sent mail is not showing in
   testing@softsolutions4u.info inbox)

My postfix log as,

```
Jul  2 12:39:18 softsolutions4u postfix/pickup[5720]: 2DC001CC08EB: uid=0 from=<root>
Jul  2 12:39:18 softsolutions4u postfix/cleanup[6640]: 2DC001CC08EB: message-id=<20160702070918.2DC001CC08EB@softsolutions4u.info>
Jul  2 12:39:18 softsolutions4u postfix/qmgr[5721]: 2DC001CC08EB: from=<root@softsolutions4u.info>, size=484, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  2 12:39:18 softsolutions4u postfix/local[6642]: 2DC001CC08EB: to=<rajasekaran@softsolutions4u.info>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.09/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jul  2 12:39:18 softsolutions4u postfix/qmgr[5721]: 2DC001CC08EB: removed
```

Its hard for me to troubleshoot. From the log I have received the mailbox but its is not visible in my Rouncubemail inbox. I have also check the folder `/home/rajasekaran/Maildir` also is can't find any new file created for the received mail.

My postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/ local_destination_recipient_limit = 300 local_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = softsolutions4u.info
myhostname = softsolutions4u.info
mynetworks = 192.168.2.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydestination
relayhost = 
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I any addition information needed to check or configured? help me in troubleshooting.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your `postconf -n`? Especially `mail_spool_directory` and `home_mailbox`.

Comment: Hi have updated my question with postconf -n @fkraiem

Comment: mail_spool_directory = /var/mail and home_mailbox =

Comment: Yes, I have seen this. It looks good on that front.